# Build Dynamic SQL "FROM" statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I've created a dynamic SQL String builder in **MS ACCESS 2013** to create reports for my users. These reports basically query data from a preset pool of fields that the user can alter using form controls. I've had no problem using conditional statements to construct the **SELECT** and **WHERE** statements however I've been using a static string based off of my table relationships to generate the **FROM** statement. I've started getting the **ambiguous outer joins** error but when I resolve it I get duplicate report data. I wanted to know if it was possible to dynamically construct a **FROM** statement based off of the fields a user selects from differing tables.

[Table relationships I copied the FROM SQL from is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9S0S.png)

Here is the static **FROM** string I'm using that's giving me the error

```sql
FROM (((((((tbl_PROJECTS_PARENT LEFT JOIN tbl_PROJECTS_CHILD ON
tbl_PROJECTS_PARENT.WR_ID = tbl_PROJECTS_CHILD.WR_ID) LEFT JOIN 
tbl_PROJECTS_FACILITIES ON tbl_PROJECTS_PARENT.WR_ID = 
tbl_PROJECTS_FACILITIES.WR_ID) LEFT JOIN tbl_SPC_GFEBS_BLDG ON 
tbl_PROJECTS_FACILITIES.FACILITY_ID = tbl_SPC_GFEBS_BLDG.Building) LEFT 
JOIN tbl_CLEARANCE ON tbl_PROJECTS_PARENT.WR_ID = tbl_CLEARANCE.WR_ID) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_RMP ON tbl_PROJECTS_CHILD.ID_WBS = tbl_RMP.ID_WBS) LEFT JOIN 
tbl_RMP_FY ON tbl_PROJECTS_CHILD.ID_WBS = tbl_RMP_FY.ID_WBS) LEFT JOIN 
tbl_COMMENTS ON tbl_PROJECTS_PARENT.WR_ID = tbl_COMMENTS.WR_ID) RIGHT JOIN 
Qry_comments_latest_basic ON tbl_COMMENTS.WR_ID = 
Qry_comments_latest_basic.WR_ID
```

I apologize for not using the code inserter. Could not get it to show entire block.

Comment: Your question isnt clear. If your question is "_I wanted to know if it was possible to dynamically construct a FROM statement based off of the fields a user selects from differing tables._" Of course you can. If you have an error with a particular "dynamically generated query", then you should post the entire query along with the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create the query with all available fields to display and query it as a new table.

```
SELECT [user selected field 1], [user selected field 2], [user selected field 3]
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_PROJECTS_PARENT
    LEFT JOIN tbl_PROJECTS_CHILD ON tbl_PROJECTS_PARENT.WR_ID = tbl_PROJECTS_CHILD.WR_ID
    LEFT JOIN tbl_PROJECTS_FACILITIES ON tbl_PROJECTS_PARENT.WR_ID = tbl_PROJECTS_FACILITIES.WR_ID
    LEFT JOIN tbl_SPC_GFEBS_BLDG ON tbl_PROJECTS_FACILITIES.FACILITY_ID = tbl_SPC_GFEBS_BLDG.Building
    LEFT JOIN tbl_CLEARANCE ON tbl_PROJECTS_PARENT.WR_ID = tbl_CLEARANCE.WR_ID
    LEFT JOIN tbl_RMP ON tbl_PROJECTS_CHILD.ID_WBS = tbl_RMP.ID_WBS
    LEFT JOIN tbl_RMP_FY ON tbl_PROJECTS_CHILD.ID_WBS = tbl_RMP_FY.ID_WBS
    LEFT JOIN tbl_COMMENTS ON tbl_PROJECTS_PARENT.WR_ID = tbl_COMMENTS.WR_ID
    RIGHT JOIN Qry_comments_latest_basic ON tbl_COMMENTS.WR_ID = Qry_comments_latest_basic.WR_ID
) AS FullData
```

Comment: I follow the logic but I'm getting a syntax error when I try to execute the query. I made sure it wasn't spacing or delimiter characters. Any idea?